# jquery datatable sorting buttons not available in header column

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, sorting, datatable

Iam using two set of table headers according to a condition jquery sorting is only applying for one set of headers

for example: if user select report type 1 - one set of table headers will show and if user select type 2 - other set of column header will show

but sorting is only available for one set of headers

```
var InspectionType = $("#InspectionType").val();

if (InspectionType == 0) {
  oTable = $('#PerformanceTableView').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "bServerSide": true,
    //                "bProcessing": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "aaSorting": [
      [0, 'desc']
    ],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
      "sEmptyTable": "<%: Resources.info_gen_norecordsavailable %>"
    },
    "sAjaxSource": actionUrl2,
    "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
      aoData.push({
        "name": "DateFrom",
        "value": DateFrom
      });
      aoData.push({
        "name": "DateTo",
        "value": DateTo
      });
      aoData.push({
        "name": "RegionName",
        "value": RegionName
      });
      aoData.push({
        "name": "Name",
        "value": Name
      });
      aoData.push({
        "name": "InspectionType",
        "value": InspectionType
      });
    },
    "aoColumns": [{
        "sName": "Job No",
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bSortable": true
      },
      {
        "sName": "Vehicle No",
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bSortable": true
      },
      {
        "sName": "TO Code",
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bSortable": true
      },
      {
        "sName": "EPF NO",
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bSortable": true
      },
      {
        "sName": "Assigned Date",
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bSortable": true
      },
    ]
  });

} else {
  oTable = $('#PerformanceTableView').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "bServerSide": true,
    //                "bProcessing": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "aaSorting": [
      [0, 'desc']
    ],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
      "sEmptyTable": "<%: Resources.info_gen_norecordsavailable %>"
    },
    "sAjaxSource": actionUrl2,
    "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
      aoData.push({
        "name": "DateFrom",
        "value": DateFrom
      });
      aoData.push({
        "name": "DateTo",
        "value": DateTo
      });
      aoData.push({
        "name": "RegionName",
        "value": RegionName
      });
      aoData.push({
        "name": "Name",
        "value": Name
      });
      aoData.push({
        "name": "InspectionType",
        "value": InspectionType
      });
    },
    "aoColumns": [{
        "sName": "Job No",
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bSortable": true
      },
      {
        "sName": "Vehicle No",
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bSortable": true
      },
      {
        "sName": "TO Code",
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bSortable": true
      },
      {
        "sName": "EPF NO",
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bSortable": true
      },
      {
        "sName": "Visited Date",
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bSortable": true
      },
    ]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> DataTables allows ordering by multiple columns at the same time, which
>   can be activated in a number of different ways:
>
> User shift click on a column (added the clicked column as a secondary,
>   tertiary etc ordering column).
>
> On a per-column basis (i.e. order by a specific column and then a
>   secondary column if the data in the first column is identical),
>   through the `columns.orderData` option. Using the `columns.orderData`
>   option to specify a multiple column order by default (for example [ 0,
>   1 ]).
>
> Through the order() API method.
>
> Note that, the ability for the user to shift click to order multiple
>   columns can be disabled through the `orderMulti` option.
>
> The example below shows the first column having a secondary order
>   applied to the second column in the table, vice-versa for the second
>   column being tied directly to the first and the salary column to the
>   first name column.

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html